# How to make paragraph show every word when browser width gets smaller?

Tags: html, css

I want the numbers 1-9 to smush together in the red box as browser width gets smaller (all numbers visible). But what happens is only the first few numbers are visible when browser width decreases.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZdeQX

```css
.hi {
  background: #ff0000;
  height: 2em;
  width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="hi">
  <p>123456789</p>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css word-wrap property. Add the following to your css.

```
.hi p {
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: it didn't work. the numbers didn't smush together when the browser got smaller.

Comment: If you remove your width on the .hi element it should work.   https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZdeQX

Answer (score 0):

I think [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#width) is what you are looking for. Basically you are setting break points for different media (e.g. screen) dimensions, for instance:

```
.hi {
    font-size: 16px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .hi {
    font-size: 12px;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .hi {
    font-size: 10px;
 }
}
```

You can use `min-width`, `max-width`, `min-height`, `max-height`, `orientation`,  combine any of those and many other options.